# How can I use Dotnet Core 1.1 CLI tooling without a project.json?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core

I've built a web app in Visual Studio 2017 RC targetting Dotnet Core 1.1. As per [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/) and elsewhere, MS have announced `project.json` is being retired and favoured for MSBUILD `.csproj` files. Problem is the `dotnet` CLI doesn't seem to work with .csproj, for instance using `dotnet ef ...` always produces an error along the lines of not finding it's binaries (even though `Add-Migration` etc. PowerShell commands work in VS) - is this due to the lack of a project.json and is there a way of getting around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.0-msbuild2-final
```

The key is msbuild part, it worked for me. For your reference, my entire .csproj is below.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" Exclude="$(GlobalExclude)" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" Exclude="$(GlobalExclude)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
      <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2-112</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc">
    <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel">
      <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql">
      <Version>1.1.1-prerelease-10012</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.0.0-msbuild2-final</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

</Project>
```